# manually rotate activity by 180 degrees

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, screen-rotation

What I am trying to do is to set the activity orientation manually at preferences screen. Lets say the default orientation is 0(regular portrait orientation) and user can go to preferences and choose lets say 180(or 90, 270). After this the activity orientation should change to the chooser option. There are methods to set portrait or landscape orientation but I cant figure out how to rotate the activity by degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to call [youractivity.setRequestedOrientation(int orientation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29).

This parameter is not the degrees, it will be a constant from ActivityInfo.

[This page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation) has some of the constants, but I guess the one you want is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mainActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);` to rotate by 180 degree if you are currently in portrait mode or `mainActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);` to rotate by 180 from Landscape mode.